# AWS Elasticbean stalk asp.net deployment file upload fails with “413 request entity too large”

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-status-code-413

I tried multiple solutions

1. I tried to add a .conf file with

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

to my root application `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf` but when deploying this to live it give me error

```
1/18/2023 11:59:22 AM           Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:[/Resources/AWSEBAutoScalingGroup/Metadata/AWS::CloudFormation::Init/prebuild_0_RisksessAML/files//etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

2.Then i tried the other way by accessing nginx.conf with SSH through putty I updated my conf file and saved it. it works fine but when ever I redeploy my code it replaces the sudo nano `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` file with a new one which do not have the `client_max_body_size 100M;` code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using `.platform/nginx/conf.d/`, not `.ebextentions` to setup `client_max_body_size` as explained in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html).

For example create `.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf` with the content of:

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```

Comment: I tried with .platform/nginx/conf.d/, not .ebextentions this time the application was deployed with no errors it is healthy but I am still getting 413 error

Comment: @muh.rafay You must have other issues. My answer correctly addresses the problem you reported with `client_max_body_size`. For other issues, please make new question with relevant details.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me was you should be using  `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/myconfig.conf` instead of just
`.platform/nginx/conf.d/myconfig.conf`

Comment: That's now what AWS docs says. Do you have any link that this is how should it be?. What ever you did, you misunderstood your setup.